# How to hide or show features/buttons based on user type/login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to hide or show some features/buttons based on user type. I'm still new in C#, Can anyone help me with it ?

Comment: webforms? MVC? Something else...?

Comment: Sir, Its a webforms.

Comment: Please go through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide and provide some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your user type/login in a session when you log into your web app.
& check user type from session value on page load.
for ex. if you have two user types: Admin & User, and you have some button let's say button ID = btnSave.

**then in your login.aspx.cs page:**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserType"] = usertype; //your usertype can be Admin or User
}
```

**then in your dashboard or another page where you want to hide your button/features .cs page**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["UserType"].ToString() == "Admin")
    {
        btnSave.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnSave.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

you can try something like this.

Comment: thanks alot sir but it came out with this if i run it in the main page.System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'